# Visa for the Maldives

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indonesian-citizens, maldives

Next month I plan to visit the Maldives for 7 days. I have an Indonesian passport, but I live in Malaysia and I have a visa.

Do I need apply for visa to go to the Maldives?

Comment: Not sure why this is in the process of being closed as unclear. The OP states his citizenship, place of residence and where he is planning on travelling. He has one question. Pretty clear cut looking to me. Plus there is an answer, answering the question asked, and accepted by the OP.

Comment: Indeed. It might be appropriate to downvote for a lack of research before posting, but the question is perfectly clear and on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You don't need a visa for the Maldives.** In fact, nobody does, as long as they have a valid passport, confirmed accommodation and a return ticket - you'll get a 30-day visa on arrival.

http://www.immigration.gov.mv/pages/entry.html

Comment: The "visa on arrival" is a mere entry stamp (not even a second separate one) so it's a visa-free entry, and "visa on arrival" is a misnomer on the part of the local authorities

Comment: 404 
Ooops... Error 404
We are sorry, but the page you are looking for does not exist.
Please check entered address and try again or  

The link is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Visa is delivered on arrival and is free of charge for ALL nationalities. Return flight tickets and proof of accommodations might be asked by the immigration on arrival.

The others possibilities for you to stay in Maldives are :

- touristic visa (free on arrival 1 month max)
- resident visa ( if you married a Maldivian national )
- work visa ( requested by your local employer prior to your arrival - 1 year maximum, can be renewed )
- business visa ( requested by your local employer/business partner prior to your arrival - 6 months max)
- Dependent visa ( if your spouse/husband works in Maldives - requested by your spouse/husband employer )